# Can I create registration page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to know can I create registration page with using javascript in html page and store all details to the client-side cookie session or I should have a database to store all information there?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Your question doesn't have enough information

Comment: This is very possible, but if you keep the registration information on the client, why would you require registration at all?

Comment: Cookies (and any kind of client storage) aren't secure, so you can't store passwords, for example.

Comment: What is the aim of this registration? As I understand all the code will be in the client side?

Comment: I am creating a website and it has a registration page, I can use serverside as well but I think it takes lots of time and I don't have that much time to finish it

Comment: for security you should NEVER save a users email and/or password client side (cookie, html5 local storage e.t.c.). on a public computer anyone could come along and harvest those details.

Answer (score 2):

This has to be server side, in a database. Why would you want to store this on users computers? What would happen if they moved to a different computer or deleted their temporary internet files? You'd cause problems.

Comment: I just want to make a registraion page for a website, I don't have time to make a database.so If I can't store data in the cookies what else I can do?

Comment: Define exactly what you mean by "registration"? In pseudocode, list what your "registration" does.

Answer (score 2):

> Hi there, I just want to know can I create registration page with using javascript in html page and store all details to the client-side cookie session

You could, but then the user would be registering with their browser rather then with your website, which doesn't appear to make sense.

> should have a database to store all information there?

Having a server side system which stores information in a database is the standard approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to persist your user information and if you want your user be able to login to your application from anywhere, then you should use a server side database and store your registration information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do that, but it would not provide any kind of security. It would also mean that you lose out on the ability to keep track of your users, unless the cookie is read by the server. Finally, your user's registration would only be valid on their computer, again unless there is a way for them to retrieve their information from the server (which means the server will need to have it).

Comment: what about password?should I include it to the table?

Comment: For a password to be meaningful, it will have to be stored serverside.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a HTML5 app you could use the localStorage and sessionStorage Objects to store your info however if the items you are collecting are security sensitive I'd send the info to a database or a protected file on the server. Leaving sensitive info in a cookie isn't wise.

If you're working with passwords, get that stuff into a database and encrypted/salted!